# AWK issue in linux

Tags: awk

I Have the following file (teste.tsv):

```
dlah_C1 ACTGTCTGTCACTGTGTTGTGATGTTGTGTGTG
blah_C2 ACTTTATATATT
blah_C3 ACTTATATATATATA
blah_C4 ACTTATATATATATA
blah_C5 ACTTTATATATT
dlah_C6 ACTTATATATATATA
dlah_C7 ACTTATATATATATA
dlah_C8 ACTTTATATATT
```

I have to print only the lines with the word "blah" from the teste.tsv file

I`ve made that command line:

```
cat teste.tsv | awk -F " " '{if($1 == "blah"){print $0}}'
```

But I Know It's wrong because I want to cat any words starting to blah. I've tried $1 == "blah*" or $1 == "blah.*" but nothing happens.

Could someone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"} $1=="blah"' Input_file
```

***OP's code issue:*** OP's logic seems to be good but first field is NOT only having `blah` but also having other things too with `_`. Do that's why it's not printing correctly.

***My fix:*** I have made `_` as field separator for all lines. Now when we compare first field with condition it will catch string `blah`

---

---

Above will look for exact word `blah` in first field in case you want to use regexp then try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"} /^blah/' Input_file
```

OR without setting delimiter:

```
awk '/^blah/' Input_file
```

Comment: Worked, but is there some possibility to do the same using the *? I`m rookie in programming yet and I fell more confortable using that logic.

Comment: @PedroHenrique, you could try `awk '/^blah.*/' Input_file` then? Which will look for lines starting with blah and then it will match anything after blah. Thought my regex `^blah` also checks samething if a line starts from it or not, kindly do lemme know if this helps you?

Comment: I can understand better now. But I have a doubt about your code, how you tell who is the column separator? In my code I used the -F " ". Thanks a lot

Comment: @PedroHenrique, by default awk's field separator is space, so I gave set field separator as `_` for all lines with `FS="_"` you could set field separator either by -F or by FS options. Kindly do lemme know in case of any more queries.

Answer (score 5):

`==` is the string comparison operator, `~` is the regexp comparison operator. Your code is using a string comparison (`==`) but trying to use regexp meta-characters (`*` and `.*` within it).

Either of these will print every line that starts with `blah`. These are doing a regexp comparison:

```
awk '/^blah/' file
awk '$0 ~ /^blah/' file
awk 'match($0,/^blah/)' file
awk 'match($0,/blah/) == 1' file
```

while these are doing a string comparison:

```
awk 'index($0,"blah") == 1' file
awk 'substr($0,1,4) == "blah"' file
```

Comment: Thank you but could you explain to me what index and the == 1 means? And I have another doubt about your code, how you tell who is the column separator? In my code I used the -F " ". Thanks a lot

Comment: Look up `index()` in the awk man page to answer your first question. Common point of English language - what you have isn't a "doubt", it's a "question" - a "doubt" is what you have when you don't believe something, not when you just want more information about something. I don't specify the field separator because I'm not using it - you want to test for **lines** that start with `blah` so you don't need to do any field splitting for that. `" "` is already the default Field Separator (`FS`) value btw, you don't need to set it to that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations. They were very valuable for my learning.

Answer (score 0):

I've tryed the following command and works too.

```
cat teste.tsv | awk -F "_" '{if($1 == "blah"){print $0}}'
```

Comment: "works" is an interesting term :-). Yes it'll produce the output you want from the input you posted BUT it employs a [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). puts the condition inside the action part of the awk body, redundantly specifies the default action given a true condition, and would stop you from easily printing any of your real fields in future (try `print $2` instead of `print $0` for example). So yeah it "works" in as much as it'll print the output you expect from the sample input you provided but you shouldn't actually use it.

Comment: To put it another way - that is NOT how you'd do this using awk and if you're not going to do it the right way in awk then you may as well just use `grep '^blah' teste.tsv`

Comment: Got it. Thank you one more time for your time.